# C++ elegant way to mark index which doesn't belong to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, unsigned

I was wondering about a proper and elegant way to mark index which doesn't belong to a vector/an array. Let me show you a brief example showing what I mean (using some pseudocode phrases):

```
std::vector<**type**> vector;

int getIndex()
{
   if (**user has selected something**)
   {
      return **index of the thing in our vector**;
   } else
      return -1;
}

int main()
{
   int selectedItem = getIndex();

   if (selectedItem<vector.size()) //checking if selected index is valid, -1 is not
   {
     **do something using selected object**
   }
}
```

Of course I mean to use it in much more sophisticated way, but I hope the problem is shown in the example. Is it a good idea to mark an index which is not in a vector using -1 constans? It leads to a warning about comparing signed and unsigned values, but still it works as I want it to.

I don't want to check additionaly if my *selectedItem* variable is -1, that gives one additional, unnecessary condition. So is this a good solution or should I consider something else?

Comment: Rather than an index, how about an iterator? Then instead of -1, you can return `vector.end()` to indicate that it is not a valid element.

Comment: boost::optional  is also useful in these sorts of situations. If  you don't have boost and can't get it, a less convenient approximation is std::pair<bool, size_t> where the bool indicates whether the pair contains a valid size_t or not.

Comment: @dlf I think cyber's answer is better. As a bonus, this maps directly to `std::find_if` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: @IdeaHat I do too. Just noting for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant way to indicate that something you're looking for wasn't found in a `vector` is to use the C++ Standard Library facilities the way they were intended -- with `iterator`s:

```
std::vector<type>::iterator it = std::find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), something_to_find);
if (it != vec.end())
{
  // we found it
}
else
{
  // we didn't find it -- it's not there
}
```

Comment: What if an iterator points to a element that has been deleted in the meantime? Is it possible to detect this kind of mistake?

Comment: In that case, your program's design is flawed.  How can the iterator point to something that was deleted?  I can think of a couple reasons.  1) Your vector is being accessed by multiple threads.  In that case, you need to protect your vector with some kind of synchronization method.  2) You are holding on to your iterators longer than you should.  Usually, iterators are treated as semi-temporary entities.  You create one by finding something, use it, and then let it go.  Rarely you may need to hold on to iterators for a long time, but in that case, you don't want to use `vector` at all.

Comment: @Rames indices won't help you in this case either - your index would point to different element or become out of bounds

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for, but what do you mean by "let it go"? Set it to vector.end()?

@AntonSavin Yes, but that at least protects from an attempt to access freed memory area (is i<v.size() is checked). But of course I agree - thats also bad when index is inidicating almost random element.

Comment: @Rames:  I mean just let it fall out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use iterators, but if you decide to stick with the indices, it's better to make `getIndex` return `size_t` as `string::find()` does:

```
 size_t getIndex()
 {
     //...
     return -1; // the same as std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
 }
```

This way `getIndex(element) < vec.size()` if and only if the element is present in vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SelectableItem {bool selected;/*more suff here*/};

struct IsSelected(const SelectableItem& sel) {return sel.selected;}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::vector<SelectableItem> vec;
   //populate vector
   auto found = vec.find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsSelected());
   if (found != vec.end())
   {
      SelectedItem& selected_item = *found;
      /*do something*/
   }
}
```

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I believe you mean:  `std::vector<SelectableItem>::iterator found = ...`

Comment: @JohnDibling yeah. This is why I love auto :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using integer indexes instead of iterators, then -1 is the usual sentinel value used to say "not found". However instead of comparing against `vec.size()` you should compare to `0` instead, to avoid the signed/unsigned mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use vec.end() then you can guard yourself against invalidated iterators (e.g. you insert an element in the vector after you have created the iterator) by compiling with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG in debug mode.

I would use -1 though, but use the size_t type everywhere. Iterators are so error prone and the ISO standard is ambiguous and diffuse when it comes to the details.